# Como exibir comentários no console do RStudio?

Tags: r

Quando escrevo um comentário (precedido pelo símbolo "#") em um script do RStudio, e aperto o comando 'Control+Enter', o meu comentário não é exibido na tela do console. Alguém saberia me informar como posso fazer os comentários do script aparecerem no console do RStudio?

Comment: Olá, Arthur, É para funcionar da maneira que você está fazendo. Qual versão do R e RStudio você está utilizando? Caso não esteja com as versões mais recentes, atualize e tente novamente. Outra opção é selecionar o comentário que você quer exibir no console e rodar. Espero te ajudado (:

Comment: Oi Arthur, podes comentar em baixo algumas duvidas em relação à tua pergunta?

Answer (score 3):

Após a versão *1.0.36* será necessário alterar uma configuração, para isso siga os passos.

1. Tools ( Ferramentas )
2. Global Options... ( Opções globais )
3. Code ( Código )

e desmarque a opção *Execute all lines in a statement*

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra opção pode ser a de atrelar um comentário a um objeto qualquer e emití-lo no Console.

Exemplo com um vetor (`x`) qualquer:

```
x<-1:10

comment(x)<-'My vector'

comment(x)

[1] "My vector"
```